# How to link up a view created page using hook_menu

Tags: views, hooks, navigation, routes

I have created a page using view and defined a path for the view. I want to add a tab using `MENU_LOCAL_TASK` from `hook_menu()` How can I add a link to the view for the page callback?

EDIT

I have tried this but does not work.

```
$items['user/%/my-fees'] = array(
        'title' => 'My Fees',
        'description' => 'Student Payment Schedule ',
        'page callback' => 'views_embed_view',
        'page arguments' => array('payment_schedules', 'user_fees', 1),
        'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
    );
```

Comment: After you edited your question I want to share my observation about MENU_LOCAL_TASK (Secondary menu tabs), that it works with sibling paths under some unique parent. See taxonomy_menu() example. http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21taxonomy%21taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_menu/7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hook_menu()` is not required. We can set the tab, or link, in the view itself under page settings -> Menu.

I have used the menu options of the view to add the item in my user navigation.

Comment: But this does not work when the view has an argument.

Answer (score 0):

Consider if you have `path/my-view` as path for your views' page.

In your custom module implement [hook_menu](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7) in this way

```
function example_menu() {
  $items['path/my-view/psudo-subpath'] = array(
    'title' => 'My Views Title',
    'type' => MENU_DEFAULT_LOCAL_TASK,
  );

  return $items;
}
```

Comment: Thanks SHuaib, please add contextual filter. My view path is user/%/my-fees with contextual filter.

Comment: Yes you can add wildcard entries in your example.